# Regular expression to match char ('-') from end of string then to the first char to the right (dot)

Tags: regex, string, filenames

I am using renaming app (Filebot) to bring order to my media files and to make media center/xbmc/plex work properly.

What would be the best and the most robust way to use regex to match "XXX" pattern in filenames like:

```
aaa.bbb.*.fff-XXX.ext
aaa.bbb.*.fff-XXX.ext1.ext2
```

I managed to work out the other bits but this looks like an unsurmountable problem for me. (Still learning.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regexp:

```
-([^-.]+)
```

will put `XXX` in capture group 1.

Comment: This works, thanks! But it turns out that the last dot (extension) is not taken into account so in my case it should actually match to the first dot or end-of-string
aaa.bbb.*.fff-XXX
aaa.bbb.*.fff-XXX.ext1

Comment: The `\.` wasn't really necessary, I've removed it. The capture group just matches any sequence of non-dot, so it will stop at either a dot or the end of string.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
-(.*?)\.
```

This will match a hyphen, followed by zero or more of any character, non-greedily, captured in group 1, followed by a period.

Another alternative would be something using lookaround assertions, like this:

```
(?<=-).*?(?=\.)
```

This will match the same type of text, except the entire match will consist of the substring between the `-` and `.`, rather than capturing that in a group.

Comment: I tried these but none is working in regex engine in app I am using. I am getting "unexpected token: ?" errors. Are they extended regular expressions?

Comment: @user2789319 The second one uses lookarounds, which are not supported by some engines (e.g. JavaScript supports lookahead but not lookbehind). However, these are nothing out of the ordinary. What regular expression engine are you using?

Comment: I could not say which engine it is, but the app is Filebot renamer.

Comment: Well I see now Filebot incorporate Groovy language.